# How to get the default font name?

Tags: fonts

How can i get the default font name? `\the\font` outputs nothing in my case. For the default font, does it use any `cmap` file?

Comment: I would recommend marking some of your questions as "answered" by clicking the "tick mark" by the answer that does best at answering the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you write `\fontname\font` instead to extract the name (and size) of the currently selected font. The first thing that comes to mind for `\the\font` is when you want to define a create to switch to what is the currently font:

```
\expandafter \let \expandafter \switchback \the\font
\font\1=cmss10\1
hello
\switchback
previous font
```

As such, `\the\font` on its own is pretty much a no-op as it switches to the currently selected font.

Comment: your code seemed that it can define a font just for some text, for others, it still used the default font. am i right?

Comment: @warem yes, but what exactly are you trying to do? Are you using LaTeX?

Comment: nothing special. i just found there was no configuration about font in my tex source. i am curious about what the default font is. then i read some document and get `\the\font` will show something. but it didn't. this is why i asked this question. but your answer is really useful tip for me.

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX keep the current values of the font attributes in internal macros. For example
`f@family` will give you the family.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\f@family
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Similarly `\f@encoding`, `\f@shape`, `\f@series` etc.

Comment: using your code, i got `cmr`. what does it mean? i can't find any cmap file about `cmr`. i only found some pk font for it in local tex directory. for a newbie, font really made me feel depressed.

Comment: @warem  Computer Modern is the family of typefaces used by default by the typesetting program TeX. It was created by Donald Knuth. (cmr is computer modern roman). Why would you get depressed over a font?

Comment: for a newbie, i start to use tex by google. it means i google something then use it in tex code. in some case, due to poor base knowledge, the code doesn't work for me but works for others. no matter how i try it, it doesn't work. it made me feel depressed.